# Start/Stop Ffmpeg video capture

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, cmd, capture

I'm currently using ffmpeg for recording video from a webcam source.

At the moment i use java to call for ffmpeg to execute.

The code is pretty straightforward

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Dualpix HD720p for Notebooks" -s cif -r 20 -f flv TEST.FLV
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + cmd);
```

and it works fine.

The only real issue occour when when i need to stop the recording process.

I know that i can press q or even ctrl+c in the CMD but i need to stop the process without keyboard input.

That would be pretty easy to achive by killing the process but in this case ffmpeg do not finalize the video leaving me with a corrupt, need to fix, output.

Is there any way to trigger the finalizing process "remotely".

Thx, 
D.

************EDIT***********************

Thx for the prompt answer, i think you're referring to

Process.getOutputStream()

As for this case i have tried with this code:

```
public Process doCommand(String cmd) throws Exception {

    rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
    recOS= proc.getOutputStream();
    regcIS= proc.getInputStream();

    return proc;

}

   receOS.write(("q/n".getBytes()));
   recOS.flush();
```

I'm  still getting an error, to be more specific, java.io.ioexception The pipe is being closed ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123118/how-to-stop-ffmpeg-that-runs-through-java-process

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952047/kill-a-process-started-by-exec-after-some-duration-and-store-frames-in-an-arra

Comment: Have you resolved this? I am trying to do the same thing. Can you share your answer. Please thanks.

Comment: @Panina , Have you resolved this? I am also facing this issue. It would be more helpful if you post your answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to send "q\n" to the ffmpeg process. To do this, first you need to get the `InputStream` using `Process.getInputStream()` and send the input.

It would be best for you to first read up a little about controlling child processes from Java. There are some good posts here on SO, search for `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

If you get stuck with the current approach, you can use Java binding to FFmpeg library via JNA

http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php

caveat: the actual link on how to build Java JNA binding under Windows is no longer available...in that case, another alternative is to use FMJ or VLCJ

More links: 
http://code.google.com/p/jjmpeg/

Comment: Hello, I am trying to implement this also. but, what makes this the correct answer?..

Comment: @oneofakind I am still perplexed of why my answer got a green approval, when my intention is more of a suggestion of using a different approach with a Java library support rather than a concrete answer on how the stop recording of the current ffmpeg process called via a Process instance.