# How to stop ffmpeg that runs through java process

Tags: java, process, ffmpeg, runtime

I am running ffmpeg in Java. Using `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` It is used to stream video through a red5 server.

My problem is that ffmpeg requires *"q"* to be pressed in order to stop. How can I do that? How can I send the q character to the running process so it will execute `p.destroy();` or something similar? At the moment it runs forever until I kill the process in the task manager. I am using Windows7.

Answer (score 2):

To inject the 'q' key into the running process, you can do something like this:

```
OutputStream ostream = p.getOutputStream(); //Get the output stream of the process, which translates to what would be user input for the commandline
ostream.write("q\n".getBytes());       //write out the character Q, followed by a newline or carriage return so it registers that Q has been 'typed' and 'entered'.
ostream.flush();                          //Write out the buffer.
```

This should successfully 'quit' the running ffmpeg process.

Comment: does this work? I am having the same problem on stopping the recording via java.

Comment: It worked for me at the time of implementation... If during the course of your own implementation you find it does not work, I'd be happy to assist with debugging it where possible. :)

Comment: This worked for me without the "\n" just "q".. and you'll need a OutputStream, do not know why but you do. BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(recordProcess.getErrorStream()));String line;
while((line = is.readLine()) != null){}

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to avoid this by passing `-nostdin` as one of the parameters for FFMpeg.  This disables user input.